# Passing Info to Included Files in Python

Tags: python, logging, include

I use the logging utility to generate and update log files for Python scripts.

However, I find that I need to edit my code in every script for which I would like to have log files for.  For instance using different directory and filenames, etc. for each separate script.

I then created an include file, i.e. loginfo.py and import this file for any script using logging.  BUT, now I am having difficulty determining a method to pass the specific directory/filename information to the included file.

Is there a better method to do this?

thanks,

EDITED to show code...

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
import os

basedir = '/home/user/LOG/'
process = 'server_backup'

LOG_DIR = basedir + process

if not os.path.exists(LOG_DIR):
    os.makedirs(LOG_DIR)

LOG_FILE = LOG_DIR +'/'+ process + '.log'
MAX_BYTES = 2000000      # MAX_BYTES is size of log file before being rotated
BACKUP_COUNT = 50       # BACKUP_COUNT is number of files logged before being

# provide names for individual log entries
logger_GEN = logging.getLogger('GEN')
# set the level of logging for each specific logger
logger_GEN.setLevel(logging.INFO)
log_handler = RotatingFileHandler(LOG_FILE, maxBytes=MAX_BYTES,     backupCount=BACKUP_COUNT)
log_handler.formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s: \t%(message)s", datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
# add the handler to the logger
logger_GEN.addHandler(log_handler)
```

I have to place this code at the beginning of any script I would like to have info logged to a file.  the only changes I make are to 'basedir' and 'process'.

I then created a file named 'loginfo.py' and when I include this, I can generate and use the log file from the main script, however; I cannot dynamically change 'basedir' or 'server' from the main script -- unless I make a method in 'loginfo.py' and send those parameters from the main script such as:

```
loginfo.create_log('basedir', 'server')
```

thanks again.

Comment: It depends on what you have to modify in each script. You could `glob.glob()` all of your `.py` files and just find-replace-write the necessary information for each file if the lines you need to alter are the same for all of them. I've done something similar for `html` files before.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't put all the above code inside a function definition that takes the needed parameters and passes back the logger object, something like `log = getLogger(basedir,  server, logger_name)`?  You would then use it in your code as `log.error(xxxx)`

Comment: awesome, thanks bivouac0!  your suggestion moved toward what I found to be the solution:

Comment: awesome, thanks bivouac0!  your suggestion moved toward what I found to be the solution.   
 
I created a function within the imported module as you suggest, however, I found that I could `return logger_GEN` and then use the base script to add info to the log file.

I can call the method by `loginfo.create_log(process)' and send messages to the logger_GEN object.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the log format?  Do this once at the start of your program...

```
log_format='[%(levelname)s %(filename)s ln=%(lineno)s] %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(level=level, format=log_format)
```

Here the filename will be included with each line of the log file.  See https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html under LogRecord attributes for various options.

Alternately, if you're wondering how to log to a file and want different filenames for each script, use `__file__` to get the filename for your current script.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I think I can find a way to incorporate this into my processes.

However, my main focus (and I apologize for not providing the necessary emphasis) is to pass information dynamically into the included file. 

Your comment regarding __file__ will allow the ability to pass the name of my script to a specific log file, but I find I have to use nearly twenty lines of code (practically all the same boilerplate) for every script I would like to provide logging for.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided code to critique.  From your description it's difficult to visualize your issue.  If you edit your original post with the code you feel is redundant, maybe someone can offer advice.

Answer (score 0):

With clues provided by bivouac0 I was able to move toward this as a solution:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
import os

basedir = '/home/user/LOG/'

def create_logger(process):

    LOG_DIR = basedir + process

    if os.path.exists(LOG_DIR):
        LOG_FILE = LOG_DIR +'/'+ process + '.log'
    else:
        os.makedirs(LOG_DIR)
        LOG_FILE = LOG_DIR +'/'+ process + '.log'

    MAX_BYTES = 2000000    # MAX_BYTES is size of log file before being rotated
    BACKUP_COUNT = 50       # BACKUP_COUNT is number of files logged before being

    # provide names for individual log entries
    logger_GEN = logging.getLogger('GEN')

    # set the level of logging for each specific logger
    logger_GEN.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    log_handler = RotatingFileHandler(LOG_FILE, maxBytes=MAX_BYTES, backupCount=BACKUP_COUNT)
    log_handler.formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s: \t%(message)s", datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    # add the handler to the logger
    logger_GEN.addHandler(log_handler)

    return logger_GEN
```

I saved the above code in a file named log_control.py and from any script I would like to provide logging for I add these lines:

```
import log_control
process = 'server'
my_logger = log_control.create_logger(process)
```

And using the logger process to add log entries with:

```
my_logger.info('%s \thandled' % process)
```